# Differentiate dead weak reference vs. nil value

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, weak-references, objective-c-runtime

As far as I know, when I dereference a dead weak reference in Objective-C, I get a `nil` value as the result. I'm wondering if there is any way to actually tell if there *was* a weak value assigned to the variable once it goes away as opposed to simply having a *value* of `nil` (for instance if the reference was never assigned).

Is there perhaps a lower-level runtime function that I can use?

I've taken to using a `BOOL` to record when the reference is assigned, but this feels ugly to me.

Comment: As far as I know, no. Note that you're not truly dereferencing the weak reference. When the object is deallocated, the reference itself is nil'd; it's not a matter of bookkeeping "is this reference still valid or not?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to tell if a weak reference has been set to `nil` because its referent has been deallocated.

The weak reference is set to `nil` by `weak_clear_no_lock` in [`objc-weak.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/objc-weak.mm).

Answer (score 4):

As Rob said, you can't do it directly.   But you can do so indirectly.

By using associated objects, you can associate a subclass of `NSObject` with the object being weakly referenced.   In that subclass, override `dealloc` to notify something that the weakly referenced object is being deallocated.

As long as you **make absolutely sure that the weakly referenced object's associated reference to your `NSObject` subclass is the *only strong reference to your subclass's instance***, then you've effectively created a means of receiving a notification of when the weakly referenced object is deallocated.

Yes, it is fragile.  One additional strong reference to that subclass's instances and the whole thing stops working.